# The server don't receive a Response / SendRequests

Tags: zend-framework

Iam new guy for Zend2 framework...I got an error which I didnt trace it...

Iam writing a controller named 'usertask' and in that fir index function i wrote the code like this

```
public function indexAction() 
{
    $sendRequest = new SendRequests;
    $tableGrid = new DynamicTable();

    $prop = array(
        'customRequest' => 'GET',
        'headerInformation' => array('environment: development', 'token_secret: abc')
    );
    $returnRequest = $sendRequest->set($prop)->requests('http://service-api/usertask');

    $returnData = json_decode($returnRequest['return'],true);        


    $tableGrid->tableArray = $returnData['result'];                
    $dynamicTable = $tableGrid->tableGenerate();                

    $view = new ViewModel(array(
                'usertask' => $dynamicTable
            ));
    //print_r($view);exit;

    return $view;   
}
```

but it is not listing my usertasks...while Iam printing $returnRequest its giving me error message like

```
The server don't receive a Response / SendRequests
```

what it the mistake in my code...could anyone suggest me...please..iam using "zend2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys I found my mistake ...I got big code but I need something like

```
public function indexAction() 
{                        
    $view = new ViewModel(array(
            'usertask' => $this->UserTable()->fetchall(),
        ));   

    return $view;   
} 
public function getUserTable()
{
    if (!$this->userTable) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->userTable = $sm->get('User\Model\UserTable');
    }
    return $this->userTable;
}
```

that's it...i got it as a list of users